VS code not highlighting the debugger line using AEM
I am using VS code Version: 1.90.2
When I am hitting the page on AEM the VS code debug gets hit, but does not highlight the line ,I need to manual go to the call stack and click the thread which will show the code trace on clicking that it shows the variables present.

Then i need to hit the step over button on debugToolBar.

Then again shows the stack trace and I need to manually click on the thread which will show the code trace, like above,
How to resolve this issue. Please provide inputs as how to resolve debugger highlight issue
Regards,
Srinivas
